# detect the end of the bootstrapping phase of the JVM

Tags: java, jvm

Is there a way to detect the end of the bootstrapping phase of the JVM?

**edit::**

so to provide a bit more context, what i am trying to do is to instrument the JDK. And this is a full blown instrumentation that records every LOAD, STORE, INVOKE byte code instruction. As the instructions are executed their data is sent to a static method, that is loaded from the xbootclasspath. This static method captures all this information and stores all of this as a trace for performing analysis at a later time.

Now, when i do this for the JDK, i do not want to disturb the way classes are loaded in the JVM, which might result in a program crash. I was guessing that the best way to go about it is to detect the point in time when the JVM is done bootstrapping, so that I can safely turn on my instrumentation thereafter. (I plan to not instrument any of the code, while the bootstrapping is taking place.) Is this even the right way to go about it?

Comment: Do you mean from inside your not yet loaded java code ? Or from an external program ? is that for loading/profiling ?

Comment: As the JVM is lazy loading, this never really occurs. You can have classes which are loaded for the first time on shutdown.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Is that true for the core classes of rt.jar ?

Comment: @dystroy It is true of all classes. Even for classes which you can be sure are loaded by the time your class starts e.g. Object, String, Class, ClassLoader, you cannot be sure every method of those classes has been loaded. e.g. if one of the methods which is not used was corrupt in some way you might never know.

Comment: @dystroy, I mean from an external java program loaded in the same JVM, (that is loaded from the Xbootpath).

Comment: I am in the same situation, are there any new learnings, vijay? BTW, we could inspect how [MAJOR](http://www.inf.usi.ch/projects/ferrari/MAJOR.html) does this or just use MAJOR, but I also want to know myself.

Comment: @kriegaex, they statically instrument the JDK itself (if i remember correctly, rt.jar). Then they basically use the instrumented rt.jar to execute any Java application they want to inspect. As for the classes of the application, they use load time instrumentation using java.lang.instrument to perform the instrumentation. So that is what i basically did. hope that helps.

Comment: Your comment and my answer crossed paths. You say: "So that is what I basically did." But you do not describe **what** you did and how you finally determined whether you are still in bootstrapping phase or not, which was your initial question. Is the suggestion I make in my answer below similar to what you did?

Comment: sorry of not being clear. what i do is that i instrument all the class es in rt.jar, re-pkg it and use it to execute all my java applications. as for the applications classes i instrument them as i mentioned above. now i thought that the first time you hit premain you one can start the instrumentation, as that will be the point where all classes would have loaded. but as Peter Lawery points out, due to lazy loading classes get loaded in-between the execution of the application. So i decided to be conservative, and i only turn on my instrumentation when i detect that i have hit the...

Comment: ... public static void main(String[]) method. Despite that, i do find classes being loaded from time to time in the execution. so in reality , i have not been able to avoid that completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my previous comment about looking into [FERRARI](http://www.inf.usi.ch/projects/ferrari/FERRARI.html) and [MAJOR](http://www.inf.usi.ch/projects/ferrari/MAJOR.html) I want to say several things:

- Both tools are only available for download as compiled Java JAR archives.
- So I wrote to the scientists who have created those tools today and asked them our question. As soon as I will receive an answer I will report back here.
- Anyway, I have looked into FERRARI's architecture and think I may have found out how they do it.

So here is my educated guess (still untested) about what you could do:

- Instrument your JDK classes.
- Add one simple class `BootstrapLock` as described below.
- Re-pack the instrumented + the new class into a modified *rt.jar*.
- Write a little dummy [Java agent](http://javahowto.blogspot.de/2006/07/javaagent-option.html) as described below.

```java
public class BootstrapLock {
    private static volatile boolean inBootstrap = true;

    public static boolean inBootstrap() {
        return inBootstrap;
    }

    public static synchronized void setEndOfBS() {
        inBootstrap = false;
    }
}

public class DummyAgent {
    public static void premain(String options, Instrumentation ins) {
        BootstrapLock.setEndOfBS();
    }
}
```

So basically the logic is as follows:

- Agents are loaded before the main application class, but after bootstrapping.
- Thus the very fact that the agent is active means that bootstrapping is finished.
- Thus the agent can switch off the global marker `inBootstrap`.
- Your instrumented classes can check the marker in order to determine if their additional instrumentation code should be bypassed or not.

I am unsure if I have enough time to test this anytime soon, but at least I wanted to post this answer here so maybe you, Vijai, can also look into it and provide some feedback. Four eyes see more than two...

---

**Update:** One of the FERRARI authors has answered my inquiry and confirmed my explanation above. You can just use a java agent as a marker of JVM having finished its bootstrapping. Maybe you do not even need the additional class, but just check if the agent has been loaded into the JVM yet. It would make things even simpler, I just do not know if it performs well. Just test it.

Comment: but even if the agent has been loaded, why is that a guarantee of the fact that the bootstrapping is completed? perhaps i am missing something basic here. thanks for the answer though!

Comment: To be more precise, it is not connected to classloading, but to calling the agent's `premain` methods. When this method is called you can call any kind of JVM code. This is also what the FERRARI guys say. Re-read what I wrote under "basically the logic is as follows".

Comment: it seems clearer now, but one final doubt: what do you mean by any kind of JVM code? do you mean that once the premain has been called, one can safely assume that executing my instrumentation code will not crash the JVM?

Comment: I dare say so. Is your experience different?

Comment: well, like i mentioned in my comments to the question above, i am conservative about it, and switch on the instrumentation once i detect that the main(String[] args) method of the application class has been loaded. And i have been testing it for at least 2 different java applications across different test cases, and it does not crash. i can test out the same thing by turning on the instrumentation when the premain is called, instead of main and reply back, later in the day. but i think it should be safe, especially since the researchers themselves suggest that same. Thanks a ton!